# Is it possible to farm the lucky coin in Terraria Mobile?

Tags: terraria-mobile

Can you farm the lucky coin in Terraria Mobile? If so, how do you do it?

Comment: Mobile version of the terraria that is?

Comment: Yes it is the mobile version of Terraria

Answer (score -2, accepted):

All you have to do is make a volcano with lava in the middle. Check this vid out:

Comment: As videos can be removed, please either provide a text instruction or a picture of the final result with some notes about how to do it  (< I recommend this), just in case.